# Google Data Studio - format date YEAR MONTH (YYYYMM) is not working

Tags: date, format, looker-studio

With Google Datastudio, 
I have 1 dimension called `createdAt`. I want to show the format `YYYYMM` in my reports:

**Tentative 1**

1/ The report show the data correctly:
[image]
2/ Change the format of the dimension `createdAt` to YYYYMM
[image]

**Tentative 2**

1/ Duplicate dimension:
[image]

2/ The report is not showing the good format for dimension `createdAt YYYYMM`:
[image]

Issue related to: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149668303#comment1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be achieved using the two step process below:

### 1) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685)

The current `createdAt` field is a `Text` field; one way to change it into a `Date` field (that Google Data Studio recognises) is using the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) function to remove the milliseconds, and the [`TODATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) function to extract a `YYYYMMDD` format:

```
 TODATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(createdAt, "(\\.\\d+)$", ""), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%Y%m%d")
```

GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

### 2) Granularity

To display the Date in a `YYYYMM` format, change the *Granularity* to *Year Month*.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c9d3d6e2-6ac5-4864-bef2-784def1054db) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]